# Insert three blocks (SQL lines) in a 100+MB SQL dump

Tags: bash, awk, sed

I've seen some sed and awk answers here but have not yet found a solution to my problem.

I've killed a mysql dump import after one hour and when I'm adding some lines to the dump the import just needs 3 minutes (like mentioned in https://support.tigertech.net/mysql-large-inserts).

I need to add some lines **after** the first occurrence of "**COMMIT;**", some lines **before** the second (which is also the last) occurrence of "**COMMIT;**" and some lines at the **end** of the file.

Since an updated dump is fetched every X weeks or months I'd love to let my scripts do this, how would you do it?

Note: The three blocks are static, so they could be text files too.

Abstract example text would be

block1.sql

```
ALTER TABLE `table1_name` DISABLE KEYS;
ALTER TABLE `table2_name` DISABLE KEYS;
ALTER TABLE `table3_name` DISABLE KEYS;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0;
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
```

block2.sql

```
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 1;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

block3.sql

```
ALTER TABLE `table1_name` ENABLE KEYS;
ALTER TABLE `table2_name` ENABLE KEYS;
ALTER TABLE `table3_name` ENABLE KEYS;
```

dump.sql

```
/* starts with SET.., BEGIN... and some CREATE TABLE... */
COMMIT;
/* insert block1.sql here */
INSERT INTO table1_name VALUES(1,2,3,4,5);
INSERT INTO table2_name VALUES(1,2,3,4,5);
INSERT INTO table3_name VALUES(1,2,3,4,5);
/* and so on, inserting all the dump data */
/* insert block2.sql here */
COMMIT;
create index index1 on table1_name(columnname);
create index index2 on table2_name(columnname);
create index index3 on table3_name(columnname);
/* and so on, creating all the indexes */
/* insert block3.sql at end of file */
```

**Update and solution**

I've modified Daweo's proposal using test files

```
#!/bin/bash

awk '{if(/^COMMIT;$/){if(!seen){print $0;while(getline<"block1.txt"){print};seen=1}else{val=$0;while(getline<"block2.txt"){print};print val}}else{print $0}}END{while(getline<"block3.txt"){print}}' testfile.tst
```

Result

```
./test-awk.sh
SET...
BEGIN...
CREATE TABLE...
CREATE TABLE...
CREATE TABLE...
COMMIT;
block 1 line 1
block 1 line 2
block 1 last line
INSERT INTO...
INSERT INTO...
INSERT INTO...
block 2 line 1
block 2 line 2
block 2 last line
COMMIT;
create index...
create index...
create index...
block 3 line 1
block 3 line 2
block 3 last line
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I need to add some lines after the first occurrence of "COMMIT;", some lines before the second (which is also the last) occurrence of "COMMIT;" and some lines at the end of the file.*

I would do it using GNU `AWK` following way, let `file.txt` content to be

```
someline1
COMMIT;
someline2
someline3
someline4
COMMIT;
someline5
```

then

```
awk '{if(/^COMMIT;$/){if(seen){print "block2";print $0}else{print $0;print "block1"};seen=1}else{print $0}}END{print "block3"}' file.txt
```

output

```
someline1
COMMIT;
block1
someline2
someline3
someline4
block2
COMMIT;
someline5
block3
```

Explanation: If whole line is `COMMIT;` I print `block2` after that line (`$0`) if such line was already seen otherwsie I print that line followed by `block1` and mark it as already `seen`. I used `END{`...`}` construct to do `print`ing of `block3` after whole file was processed.

Disclaimer: this solution assumes was is inserted is etched in stone and will never change, thus might be hard-coded. Use `\n` if you want multiline insertions, for example replacing `"block1"` using `"block1A\nblock1B"` yield

```
someline1
COMMIT;
block1A
block1B
someline2
someline3
someline4
block2
COMMIT;
someline5
block3
```

*(tested in gawk 4.2.1)*

Comment: Thanks, I'll update my question with the solution from your proposal.

Answer (score 1):

Using the `ed` text editor (Does require enough memory to load the file; hopefully not an issue with just 100-odd MB):

```sh
ed -s dump.sql <<'EOF'
/^COMMIT;$/r block1.sql
/^COMMIT;$/-1r block2.sql
r block3.sql
w
EOF
```

What this does:

- Open `dump.sql` and load its contents into the edit buffer, then apply all the commands given in the heredoc.
- **r**ead the contents of `block1.sql` into the edit buffer immediately after the first `COMMIT;` line.
- Read the contents of `block2.sql` into the edit buffer immediately before the next `COMMIT;` line.
- Read and append the contents of `block3.sql` to the end of the buffer.
- **w**rite the buffer to `dump.sql` and quit.

---

And an inline version that doesn't use the extra files:

```sh
ed -s dump.sql <<'EOF'
/^COMMIT;$/a
ALTER TABLE `table1_name` DISABLE KEYS;
ALTER TABLE `table2_name` DISABLE KEYS;
ALTER TABLE `table3_name` DISABLE KEYS;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 0;
SET AUTOCOMMIT = 0;
.
/^COMMIT;$/i
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS = 1;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
.
$a
ALTER TABLE `table1_name` ENABLE KEYS;
ALTER TABLE `table2_name` ENABLE KEYS;
ALTER TABLE `table3_name` ENABLE KEYS;
.
w
EOF
```

This version introduces **a**ppend, which inserts text after the given line, and **i**nsert, which inserts before the given line, as well as `ed`'s *input mode*, where the lines after the command up to the first one that just has a period are what that command inserts.